# How to count the number of checkboxes ticked which is inside a listview

Tags: java, android, list, listview, checkbox

I have an custom array adaptor which is handling a list view.
Each row has two checkboxes. There are five rows in total.
I want to be able to count the number of checkboxes ticked and then display this number in Stand1

So basically  the project Layout is like this

Inside stand1 there is a list view and a text view.
The stand1.java calls an array adapter Called CustomArrayAdaptor.
I want to be able to count the number of checkboxes clicked and send that data back to the stand1

I am quite new to android development so if somebody can be able to push me in the right direction, it would be great.

Here is my code

**Stand1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="446dp"
    android:id="@+id/Stand1list"
    android:scrollIndicators="right"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true">


</ListView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send Score To Databse"
        android:id="@+id/sendtodb"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Stand1list"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="8/10"
        android:id="@+id/Score"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sendtodb"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

**Row_Layout1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textelement"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:longClickable="false" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/Checkbox1"
        android:button="@drawable/checkboxcustom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" />
    <CheckBox

        android:button="@drawable/checkboxcustom"
        android:id="@+id/Checkbox2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Stand1.java**

```
public class Stand1 extends Fragment {
    ListView mList;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stand1,container,false);
        mList = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.Stand1list);
        return root;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        populateListView();
    }

    private void populateListView() {
        String[] pair = {"Pair 1","Pair 2","Pair 3","Pair 4","Pair 5"};

        //build adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new CustomArrayAdaptor(getActivity(),pair);

        mList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**CustomArrayAdaptor.java**

```
public class CustomArrayAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<String>{


    public CustomArrayAdaptor(Context context, String [] Pairs) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout1, Pairs);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View CustomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout1, parent, false);
        String stringelement = getItem(position);
        TextView Text= (TextView)CustomView.findViewById(R.id.textelement);

        Text.setText(stringelement);
        return CustomView;
    }




}
```

Thanks Folks

Comment: You'll need to keep track of the checked state in your custom adapter. Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/28408710/995891 - then simply count the `true`s in `checkboxState`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a few things to your **CustomArrayAdaptor** and tested it, see below:

```
    public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    int checkAccumulator;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, String [] Pairs) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout1, Pairs);
        checkAccumulator = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout1, parent, false);
        String stringelement = getItem(position);
        TextView Text = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textelement);

        CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) customView.findViewById(R.id.Checkbox1);
        CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) customView.findViewById(R.id.Checkbox2);

        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        countCheck(isChecked);
                        Log.i("MAIN", checkAccumulator + "");
                    }
                };

        checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);
        checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkListener);

        Text.setText(stringelement);
        return customView;
    }

   private void countCheck(boolean isChecked) {

        checkAccumulator += isChecked ? 1 : -1 ;
    }
}
```

1. Added **int checkAccumulator** to keep track of how many items have been clicked.
2. Added two **CheckBox** Views for the purpose of tracking checks.
3. Added **CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener** that calls a new **countCheck** method everytime any checkBox is checked / unchecked. We pass the **isChecked** boolean to track whether we need to add or subtract from our **checkAccumulator**.
4. Added **countCheck** function that adds or subtracts *1* dependent on the boolean. Sorry for the obfuscated code, for all those who aren't used to the ? conditional it is basically saying *if true add 1, else add -1.*
5. Not sure what you wanted to do with the check count, so I added a  **Log.i("MAIN", checkAccumulator + "");** just so you can watch the *Android Monitor* to ensure that it is actually working.

Should work for you.

Comment: Glad to help. A couple of more points: make sure your *.xml* files are always all lower case. Also, regarding **TextView Text** and **View CustomView** ... **Text** and **CustomView** should be lowercase. Upper case first letters are reserved for class definitions, not class instances. Even StackOverflow is confused by the capitalization and has colored them like classes. Good luck to you.

Comment: As a bonus question, would you be able to tell me how i can set the textview of Score in stand1.xml to checkAccumulator?

Thanks about naming, Quite new to this, so will try and fix that after a while

Comment: One way to do it is with an interface. It's a slightly involved process, and you may want to pose it as a new question. Maybe you can figure it out from here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: cheers. Should be able to find it out from there. Really appreciate the help

Comment: @Selvin I disagree, this is just a part of the solution. Your valid critique has been pointed out twice on this thread already. I don't think any questioner is expecting the responder to rewrite the whole app. How do you know that the questioner didn't provide us with a reduced code-base in order to make answering the question easier?

Comment: You disagree with what? That your solution is working as i said(so in fact it is not working)?

Comment: @Selvin I suggest you edit the solution, add your own, or provide us with more specific improvements in the comments.

Comment: The link provided doesn't mention how to count checked boxes. Would you like me to add code to save the states of the checked boxes? Would you like to provide us with the code?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should recycle your views in the adapter:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout1, parent, false);
    }
```

After that, I think you should save the state of each checkbox in your data source or just keep a list, the same size of your pair array, and save it there using the position you get from getView.